# Map a url to a subdomain (NGINX)

Tags: nginx, configuration, subdomain

I know this question has been [asked before on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14711666/mapping-subdomains-to-urls-with-nginx) but I'm having trouble replicating it on my server.

What I'm trying to do is when the user goes to `medicine.example.com`, the subdomain should be mapped to `example.com/sites/medicine`.  So the URL the user sees is `medicine.example.com`. index.php is stripped off via php.

Ideally, the solution would be a wildcard/regex-based such that more than just `medicine.example.com` could be mapped to url.

The below code gives me a `502 bad gateway` error.

```
server {
    listen      80;
    listen      443 ssl;
    server_name medicine.example.com;

    location / {
        rewrite             ^([^.]*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;
        proxy_pass_header   Set-Cookie;
        proxy_pass          https://example.com/sites$request_uri;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want an HTTP redirect or internal rewrite? Is `example.com` served by the same webserver?

Comment: hi @mgorven, im looking for an internal rewrite, I want to keep the subdomain as the URL, yes example.com is also served by the same web server

Answer (score 3):

You don't really want to proxy requests to the same webserver, it requires more overhead. I would configure a single virtual host for both domains, and use an [`if`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule#if) statement to only rewrite requests for the subdomain.

```
server {
    server_name example.com medicine.example.com;

    if ($host = "medicine.example.com") {
        rewrite . /sites/medicine$request_uri;
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: hmm, medicine.example.com redirects to example.com regardless of whether I put your `rewrite` condition in. So it looks like I have a problem somewhere else in my nginx.conf. [Here's my full nginx.conf if that's helpful](https://gist.github.com/tim-peterson/5136554). Also, is `proxy request` the same as `internal rewrite`?

Comment: @timpeterson Then something else in your config is redirecting. Also check `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/` for config. Proxying is not the same as rewriting -- proxying should only be used when forwarding to a different web server.

Comment: @mgovern thanks, my `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` is empty so I'm pretty sure my nginx.conf is the only thing that is contributing. Would mind taking a look at the nginx.conf file i included as a gist? https://gist.github.com/tim-peterson/5136554

Comment: @timpeterson I can't spot anything which would cause that. Try commenting out `rewrite` statements until it stops doing that.